# Are there equations which have solutions in all groups but which are not algebraicly solvable

Tags: group-theory

I am not sure exactly how to phrase this problem so I appologise if it is not clear, also this is somewhat long but I wanted to explain exactly where I was with the problem. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

---

**Description of Problem**

Given a set of variables $\{x,y,z,...\}$ and a variable $o$ is it possible to define a finite product of these variables and their inverses $\sigma(x,y,z,...,x^{-1},y^{-1},z^{-1},...,o,o^{-1})$ (i.e. a finite sequence made up of these variables and their inverses) such that;

1) For any group $G$ and any assignment of values from $G$ to $\{x,y,z,...\}$ there exists a unique element $g$ of $G$ such that if $o$ is set to $g$;

$\sigma(x,y,z,...,x^{-1},y^{-1},z^{-1},...,o,o^{-1})=1$

and

2) There does not exist a finite product $\gamma(x,y,z,...,x^{-1},y^{-1},z^{-1},...)$ such that;

$o=\gamma(x,y,z,...,x^{-1},y^{-1},z^{-1},...)$ for all groups $G$

---

**Rough explaination as to why I am asking here**

My intuition is no but I am unsure how to prove this. There are clearly examples of equations like these solvable in all groups (i.e. $xo=1$) but these have algebraic solutions (in that example $o=x^{-1}$) and there are examples of these equations which are solvable in wide classes of groups (i.e. $o^{n!+1}x=1$ is solvable in any group of order less than $n$ with $o=x^{-1}$) but these are not solvable in all groups. In addition some equations are solvable in all groups but not uniquely (i.e. $o^2=1$ has many solutions in groups with elements of order 2 but can always be solved with $o=1$)

---

**Progress on proof (or proof of falsehood)**

It can be shown that $\sigma$ must contain exactly $\pm1$ total occurences of $o$ (where $o^{-1}$ counts as $-1$ occurence of o) using the following argument.

If $G$ is abelian then $\sigma$ can be written as $Ao^n$ for some $A$ which is a product of the other variables. For this to be solvable $o^n=A^{-1}$ must be solvable in every abelian group. If $A=1$ $o$ is not uniquely defined for groups of order $|n|$. If $A\neq1$ and $|n|\neq1$ then $o$ is not defined for groups of order $|n|$ or $n=0$ and so $o$ is not unique. Therefore $|n|=1$ and so the total number of occurences of $o$ in $\sigma$ must be $\pm1$.

In addition it is clear that there must be an odd number of occurences of $o$ greater than $1$ (this time counting $o^{-1}$ as $1$ occurence). This follows as otherwise there is a clear definition of $\gamma$ (if there is $1$ occurence) or the observation above is violated (if there are an even number of occurences).

This is where I am and I am not sure how to proceed. Appologies again for this being overly long. Any information or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your 2nd question is unclear. For the first question, consider the equation $\sigma(x,x^{-1},o,o^{-1})= xx^{-1} ooo^{-1}=1$. It has unique solution $o$, namely $o=1$.

Comment: It perhaps wasn't clear that the two statements must both be simultaneously true. I am not sure how to clarify the 2nd statement

Comment: I see. The second part is unclear since you did not quantify $x, y$, etc.: Do you mean to say that there is no word $\gamma$ in formal variables ..., such that for each group  $G$ the equation $o=\gamma(...)$ has a solution in $G$?

Comment: I suppose it would best be described as given $\sigma(x,...,o,o^{-1})$ there is no function given as a word $\gamma(x,...)$ s.t $\sigma(x,...\gamma(x,...),(\gamma(x,...))^{-1})=1$ in any group under any assignment of values of x,y,...

Comment: Maybe another way to explain it is to give the intuition behind the idea. If when we define a word we don't allow inverses then the word$\sigma(x,o)=xo$ would be a valid solution as there is always a unique solution by definition of a group but there is no way of writing this solution without using $x^{-1}$ and so in terms of words only using $x$ we cannot write $\gamma(x)$ s.t $x\gamma(x)=1$ in all groups. Maybe this has made things more clear, maybe not. To clarify this is not a solution of the problem as in the problem we are allowed $x^{-1}$

Comment: This is even less clear now: The questions written in the comment seem to be different from the problem in the main body of your post. One more thing: There is now a substantial literature on equations in groups. Let me know if you want to see some references.

Comment: References would be great. To be honest I wasn't really expecting anyone to respond to this so I guess I wasn't too clear about what I meant. I expect that I will probably get the best results by looking into it myself but I would like to be able to explain my question clearly. Could you try to explain what makes the questions in the comments seem so differnt from the ones in the post. To be clear I think the the questions in the comments are more accurate to what I want to ask.

Comment: Take a look at references (equations in groups) on this web page: http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~zlil/

Comment: Thank you for the references. They will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I have no answered my question. If this doesn't seem like an answer it is probably due to me being unable to clearly describe the question I wanted to ask so sorry. Also I'm not sure how best to explain the answer.

---

It can be shown that no such equation exists by contradiction. First assume there exists $\sigma$ as is required by the problem. Let $n$ be the number of variables it takes (excluding $o$ and only counting $x$ not $x^{-1}$ for example). Take the group $F_n$ (the free group with $n$ generators) and assign to each of the variables that $\sigma$ takes $x_1,x_2,...$ a different one of the generators $g_1,g_2,...$. Find the value of $o$ corresponding to this situation. By definition of $F_n$, $o$ can be written as a finite product of $g_1,g_2,...$. Write $\gamma$ as this representaion of $o$ but where the generators are replaced by the corresponding variables. Therefore by definition of the free group in all groups $o=\gamma$ is a solution.

---

Sorry if this wasn't clear. Also thanks to Santana Afton for mentioning using the free group in there answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you require uniqueness of your solution, then I don’t believe this is possible.

To shorten notation, for a set $X$ I’ll write $\sigma(X)$ to denote a word in elements of $X$. Let $X$ be a set, let $o$ be a variable, and let $\sigma(X, o)$ be any word. Then the group

$$G = \langle X, s, t~|~\sigma(X, s) = \sigma(X, t) = 1\rangle$$

fails the uniqueness condition for solutions to $\sigma(X, o)$.

---

So, let’s consider the case where we don’t assume uniqueness. In this case, it is (uninterestingly) possible.

The requirement that $\sigma(X, o) = 1$ for **all** groups means that, in particular, this must be true for the free group $F(X\cup\{o\})$. This means that $\sigma(X,o)$ must reduce to a trivial word by the definition of free groups.

The only next requirement is that $o\notin \langle X\rangle$. Thus, we can produce a situation you want in the following way: let $G$ be any group with identity element $e$, and $\sigma(X,o)$ be any word that reduces to the trivial word.

Then, the assignment $x\mapsto e$ for all $x\in X$ and $o\mapsto g$ for any $g\ne e$ in $G$ satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Firstly thank you for the answer. I will first tackle the second part of your answer, I did not make it clear that the word should be solvable for all assignments of variables to X. i.e. we cannot simply say that all of them are e unless the group is only e. The first part of your answer is more of interest to me as I just want to prove it impossible. I'm not sure how one would explicitly construct the group you describe. As in for some particular $\sigma$ (for example $xox$) how would we construct the desired group. It would be nice if you could respond, so9rry again for how unclear I was.